# I am trying to set up a Contact Us form in my React App using AWS SES, but error that "CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, contact-form, amazon-ses

I have created an email template.

```
{
    "Template": {
        "TemplateName": "testemplate",
        "SubjectPart": "Test email for first name: {{firstName}}",
        "TextPart": "Test email body!",
        "HtmlPart": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Test Title<\/title>\r\n<\/head>\r\n<body>\r\n    <h1>First Name : {{firstName}}<\/h1>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
    }
}
```

I set up my configuration using my region, AWSAccessKeyID, AWSSecretKey using the AWS configuration CLI.

This is the function that I am running:

```
var params = {
        Destination: { /* required */
            CcAddresses: [
            'MY_EMAIL',
            /* more CC email addresses */
            ],
            ToAddresses: [
            'MY_EMAIL',
            /* more To email addresses */
            ]
        },
        Source: 'MY_EMAIL', /* required */
        Template: 'testemplate', /* required */
        TemplateData: '{ \"firstName\":\"firstName\" }', /* required */
        ReplyToAddresses: [
            'MY_EMAIL'
        ],
        };

        var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
        sendPromise.then(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(
            function(err) {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
            }
        );
    }
```

And when I fill out my form locally, I am still getting the console error in that "CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config".

Do I need to set up a separate config file containing my accesskey, etc when using AWS SES? And if yes, how so? I originally thought configuring m credentials via AWS SES CLI would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to set the credentials outside of the CLI - if you deploy your code the CLI creds are not going with it.

I'm not sure with AWS but you actually might need to implement a backend to handle sending the contact forms info. The credentials should not be exposed on the front end (security risk) so you should be sending the payload of the contact form to an API that the backend can consume and then send on to AWS.

Front end > backend (with creds) > AWS